# EF Code First Migrations running DbMigrator.Update fails

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

In my ASP.NET MVC Web App backed by EF Code First using EF Migrations, I need better control of DB Updates, making them semi-automatic. The goal is to run them from code only (e.g. by running `DbMigrator.Update()`) but if not run, the application should still execute, ignoring possible alterations.

To accomplish this, I'm setting `DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to `false`, but during the first database access, I'm hitting the following Exception:

> **System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException**: 'Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.'

The good part: I was able to omit the Exception by setting `disableDatabaseInitialization="true"` in `Web.config` as [described at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#database-initializers) (I didn't find any other working way).

I'm running the following code on a custom trigger:

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false,
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false,
    MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(InitialCreate)),
    MigrationsNamespace = typeof(InitialCreate).Namespace
};

var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);

migrator.Update(); // throws Exception
```

The Update call throws:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: 'There is already an object named 'MyEntity' in the database.'

This might have something to do with the use of `disableDatabaseInitialization`. Also, the call to `migrator.GetLocalMigrations()` lists all the Migrations but `migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations()` lists none (empty), while there are already some Migrations applied.

Can you spot the error?

Answer (score 3):

After lots of trying, I was able to find out myself, the missing `ContextKey` Property caused the issues:

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false,
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false,
    MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(InitialCreate)),
    MigrationsNamespace = typeof(InitialCreate).Namespace,

    ContextKey = nameof(MyContext) // Fixed the issue
};
```

Very interesting that I have to set all the fields myself. In the examples I found, people didn't need to setup anything.

Comment: For me it was `MigrationsAssembly` and `MigrationsNamespace` that were missing. I had `ContextKey` already, but it's hardcoded. I have an existing database. I thought I'd use your `nameof` because it's cleaner, but it doesn't return the same string as the hardcoding so I ended up with an error about entities existing in the database already.